# Javascript: how to set Option value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
    ({
        loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
       for (var i=0;i<=5;i++){
       var opts = [
        { value:i, label:i },
       ];

        component.set("v.options", opts);
}

}

})
```

REQUIREMENT: opts must contains 0,1,2,3,4....

Comment: You erased the opts value for each element of the foor loop.

Comment: for (var i=0;i<=100;i++) I need all I value in opts....If I display in component it must display 0,1,2,3...99....Got it?.......

Comment: I got it obviously. What I'm trying to say is that in your for loop, you set the opts value for each element. Does this sound normal to you? You should push each value to opts array. Not erasing its value.

Comment: okay..please post the code...after pushing to the array..itsnt working..

Comment: In js side try this code:  ({
 loadOptions : function(component, event, helper) {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
     fruits[6] = "Lemon";   
        component.set("v.options", fruits );
 }
})...I need all fruit value in component...suppose if I add more values means its tedious task

Comment: just use one temp variable to push the value each time in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop, you erase the value of the `opts` array for each element.

First, you must declare the `opts` array. Then, in your for loop, just push the element to the array. Finally, set the `options` value using the `opts` array outside and after the for loop:

```
({
    loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
       var opts = [];
       for (var i=0;i<=5;i++){
          opts.push({ value:i, label:i });
       }
       component.set("v.options", opts);
   }

})
```

Comment: absolutely you are right..this what I expected....thanks